# AddObserver forkeypath:: not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code which I'm using to try and observe a variable, and regenerate text when it changes. But so far nothing happens:/

```
-(void)viewdidload{    
    float Index = 1;//declared in header locally
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"Index" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];

    [self generateAdviceText];
 }   



-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
NSLog(@"inside");
if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"Index"]){
    NSLog(@"INDEX CHANGED");
    [self generateAdviceText];
}
}

-(void)generateAdviceText{
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString *name = ((User *)appDelegate.users[self.currentUserIndex]).name;
NSString *clothWear = @"HAT";

NSMutableAttributedString *adviceString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\"..."];
[adviceString appendAttributedString:[self boldString:name]];
[adviceString appendAttributedString:[self normalString:@", remember be extra aware of the cats today. The index is "]];
[adviceString appendAttributedString:[self boldString:[@(Index) stringValue]]];
[adviceString appendAttributedString:[self normalString:@", sth "]];
[adviceString appendAttributedString:[self boldString:clothWear]];
[adviceString appendAttributedString:[self normalString:@" sth "]];
[adviceString appendAttributedString:[self boldString:sth]];
[adviceString appendAttributedString:[self normalString:@"...\""]];

self.adviceLabel.attributedText = adviceString;
```

}

Can anybody spot my mistake? Thanks

Comment: How is Index declared? Are "inside" and "INDEX CHANGED" logged out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key-Value Observing does not generate change notifications for simple assignments to instance variables (or any other kind of variable).

In most cases, you need to call the setter of the property to generate a change notification for that object and that property.

At a low level, KVO only generates change notifications if the `-willChange...` and `-didChange...` methods from the [`NSKeyValueObserving` informal protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/) are called. Those methods are called in specific circumstances:

- If a properly-named setter or collection mutation accessor for the property named by the key is called (assuming `+automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:` return true for that key). This is the best way.
- If one of the `-set...` methods from the [`NSKeyValueCoding` informal protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/index.html), such as `-setValue:forKey:`, is called (again, assuming `+automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:` return true for that key).
- If a collection proxy returned by one of the `-mutable...ValueForKey:` methods of the `NSKeyValueCoding` is sent mutation methods (again, depends on `+automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:`).
- If some code (usually in the class defining the property) manually calls the `-willChange...` and `-didChange...` methods.

As Joe Shang noted, though, it's questionable for an object to observe itself. If an object wants to know when one of its properties has been changed, it should put the relevant code into its setter. Of course, it then has to modify its property exclusively using that setter, never by setting the instance variable directly (just like for KVO).

In the code you posted, though, it's just as well that you didn't get the KVO change notifications you expected. Your code would infinitely recurse until it crashed when it overflowed the stack. You attempted to make it so that changing the index calls `-generateAdviceText` and that `-generateAdviceText` changes the index.

Comment: Just for clarity I added that increment deliberately to make sure that Index was changed; how do you mean I didn't get the change notification I expected? Also, Index is a float variable! I don't know when I didn't step across that the observed property has to be a.... property. Im sorry for not making this more clear (also that I didn't write an endless loop program:);)

Comment: How would be the right way for an object to observe an object? You're saying that its questionable to observe oneself. I just wanted to observe a variable (not knowing it had to be a property to work), hence invoking add observer on self (due to variable being in this scope) with parameter self (because -observeValueForkeyPath:: is implemented here). I think I might have got some understanding twisted... Thanks for your useful post. ill bbl later to put answer

Comment: This whole question is because you expected to get a change notification (call to `-observeValueForKeyPath:...`) and you didn't. I was saying it's just as well that you didn't because your program would have gone into infinite recursion. I'm not sure why you think it's significant that `Index` is a float variable. KVO is often the right tool for an object to observe another object for a change in its properties. However, there's rarely a good reason for an object to use KVO to observe its **own** properties, because it can just put code into the setter and cut out the middle man.

Comment: The reason that I was focused on the float variable was indeed that KVO only works with properties. I didn't declare this as a property, just as a private variable. Changing this to a property made the whole thing work. Just one last thing, since its only a good idea to use KVO on "others" properties: isn't it always possible to implement some kind of responsive behaviour in any getter wherever? Or maybe when you want a function from "self" called as a response to a change in value of a property from a different class (that doesn't have access to self methods) is a scenario? Thx!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "some kind of responsive behaviour in any getter wherever". Also, "change in value of a property from a different class" is ambiguous. Do you mean a change in the value of another object's property? Or do you mean when some other class changes the value of this class's property? If the latter, how would that other class do that if not by calling some method on this class? (Direct access to public instance variables is horrible. Don't ever allow that.)

Comment: Well, based on this whole thread I was of the notion that its well-doing to place responsive behaviour( i mean whatever code to invoke when something happens(in this case change of a value) in the setter. I did also mean "change in value of a property contained in another class," obv not the latter. I appreciate your thoroughness in this, and your fine help.

Comment: So basically. would a good scenario for KVO use be when self (a view controller) want to observe a property of another class (where you can't get the sufficient access to "self"(the vc) from the setter method)

Comment: Yes, in general, KVO is for observing other objects for changes in their properties. The class which implements the property has to implement it in a KVO-compliant manner. Not all properties are (because, for example, the class directly modifies its instance variables like you originally did). For your own classes, you control that. For classes from system or third-party frameworks or libraries, you have to check the documentation to see if it promises that a property is KVO-compliant.

Answer (score 1):

What's the `Index` type? static variable or property? The keyPath in `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:contexts:` must be the property of some object (KVC compatible), you can read [NSHipster's acticle](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/) and [objc.io #7](http://www.objc.io/issue-7/key-value-coding-and-observing.html) to get more.

In the other hand, if `Index` is property, you don't need to use KVO here. You can override the setter method of `Index` and do some action when `Index` is update.

```
- (void)setIndex:(int)index
{
    _index = index;
    // add you generateAdviceText method here
}
```

Comment: Index is indeed a float... which cannot be declared as a property. When you say if index is a property, I don't need to use KVO here. When would be an appropriate scenario to use KVO? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think that a property can't be of `float` type?

Comment: tbh I think initially I have come across using some property keywords that only works with objects, and have resorted to either using NSInteger as property or just declaring primitive types in the implementation. As i also said in comment below, I think thats what got me all confused about the variable being float. Foolish I know, but at least now corrupted memory has been fixed:) Just disregard this comment, and answer below if you would. Thanks for your help